# AWS lambda+seleniumでHTMLが描画されない

Tags: python, aws, selenium, aws-lambda

AWS lambda上でSelenium(python)を用いて

https://app.squadbeyond.com/

このサイトをスクレイピングしようとしています。

ローカルではうまくいくのですが、AWS上で実行しようとすると、画面が真っ白でHTML要素が表示されません。

time.sleepやwait系の類は何度も試しているので違います。
また、UA偽装も関係ありませんでした。

何か他にやり方はありますか？

Comment: 質問に関連するコード等も提示してください。「ローカルでは動く」ということですが、各環境のバージョン等は揃った状態なのでしょうか？